# My SDL2 program builds up memory usage over time

Tags: c++, memory, sdl

This is surely me being bad at optimizing, but I can't figure it out. I started using SDL2 a few days ago and I built a simple "game" if we want to say that. The memory usage gets higher and higher every frame(starting at 50mb but goes up to almost 2gb really fast) and I don't know how to solve it. I'm almost positive that it is caused by using too much IMG_Load(). Please help, here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>


//mouse handler
int handleMouseClick(SDL_MouseButtonEvent& button) {
    if (button.button == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        return 2;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize the SDL2 library\n";
        std::cout << "SDL2 Error: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //initialize ttf lib
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("citybuilder",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        960, 960,
        0);
    TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("Sans.ttf", 24);
    SDL_Color White = { 255,255,255 };

    //Load surfaces and textures
    
    
    SDL_Surface* window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Surface* background = IMG_Load("background.bmp");
    SDL_Surface* handitem = IMG_Load("item1.png");
    SDL_Surface* text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: House" , White);

    //setting a rectangle to change player position
    SDL_Rect handObject;
    handObject.x = 10; 
    handObject.y = 10;
    handObject.w = 40;
    handObject.h = 40;

    //objects on the board
    SDL_Rect objectsOnBoard[576];
    SDL_Surface* tableTexture[24][24];
    bool table[24][24] = {false};
    
    //mouse and keyboard positions and states
    int mousex, mousey;
    const Uint8* keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    
    //errors
    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window\n";
        std::cout << "SDL2 Error: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }else std::cout << "Window successfully loaded.\n";

    if (!window_surface) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get the surface from the window\n";
        std::cout << "SDL2 Error: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }else std::cout << "Got window surface.\n";
    
    //show instructions on console
    std::cout << "Instructions:\n\tYou switch elemnts with the numbers.\n\t1 - House\n\t2 - Road(E-W)\n\t3 - Road(N-S)\n\t4 - Junction\n\t5 - Park\n";
    
    //window events
    bool windowOpen = true;
    bool place = false;
    bool remove = false;
    int objectAmount=0;
    int placex, placey;
    int hand = 1;
    while (windowOpen) {
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mousex, &mousey);
        place = false;
        remove = false;
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) > 0) {

            switch (e.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                windowOpen = false;
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                //place object
                
                if (handleMouseClick(e.button) == 1) {
                    place = true;
                    //std::cout << "Leftclick\n";
                }
                if (handleMouseClick(e.button) == 2) {
                    remove = true;
                    //std::cout << "Rightclick\n";
                }
            }
            
        }

        //move held item to mosue
        handObject.x = mousex;
        handObject.y = mousey;
        
        if (place) {
            placex = mousex / 40;
            placey = mousey / 40;
            //std::cout << placex << " " << placey << "\n";
            if (!table[placex][placey]) {
                objectsOnBoard[objectAmount].x = placex*40;
                objectsOnBoard[objectAmount].y = placey*40;
                objectsOnBoard[objectAmount].w = 40;
                objectsOnBoard[objectAmount].h = 40;
                objectAmount++;
                table[placex][placey] = true;
                if (hand == 1) {
                    tableTexture[placex][placey] = IMG_Load("item1.png");
                }
                if (hand == 2) {
                    tableTexture[placex][placey] = IMG_Load("item2.png");
                }
                if (hand == 3) {
                    tableTexture[placex][placey] = IMG_Load("item3.png");
                }
                if (hand == 4) {
                    tableTexture[placex][placey] = IMG_Load("item4.png");
                }
                if (hand == 5) {
                    tableTexture[placex][placey] = IMG_Load("item5.png");
                }
            }
        }
        if (remove) {
            placex = mousex / 40;
            placey = mousey / 40;
            //std::cout << placex << " " << placey << "\n";
            if (table[placex][placey]) {
                table[placex][placey] = false;
                
            }
        }
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_1]) {
            
            hand = 1;
            
        }
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_2]) {
            
            hand = 2;
            
        }
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_3]) {
            
            hand = 3;
            
        }
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_4]) {
            
            hand = 4;
            
        }
        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_5]) {
            
            hand = 5;
            
        }
        
        switch (hand) {
        
        case 1 :
            handitem = IMG_Load("item1.png");
            text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: House", White);
            break;
        case 2:
            handitem = IMG_Load("item2.png");
            text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Road1", White);
            break;
        case 3:
            handitem = IMG_Load("item3.png");
            text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Road2", White);
            break;
        case 4:
            handitem = IMG_Load("item4.png");
            text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Junction", White);
            break;
        case 5:
            handitem = IMG_Load("item5.png");
            text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Park", White);
            break;

        }
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, window_surface, NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < objectAmount; i++) {
            if (table[objectsOnBoard[i].x / 40][objectsOnBoard[i].y / 40]) {
                SDL_BlitSurface(tableTexture[objectsOnBoard[i].x / 40][objectsOnBoard[i].y / 40], NULL, window_surface, &objectsOnBoard[i]);
            }
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(handitem, NULL, window_surface, &handObject);
        SDL_BlitSurface(text, NULL, window_surface, NULL);

    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I know I could be using textures, would this solve the problem?

Comment: `handitem = IMG_Load("item5.png");` youre constantly reloading these images and afaict youre never releasing that memory. why dont you just load it once and pick the right one?

Comment: So I could use a data type that holds an image and load the all the images once and just select them afterwards? Or do i just make a surface for every item and do `handitem=item1` for example?

Comment: @LászlóLipódi Hello, you may want to make your code example a bit smaller so people looking at the question can see relevant information faster, welcome to SO!

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain thank you for the kind words, I sadly didn't see the notification as I wasn't so active on SO since. I'll try to make my code examples shorter in my post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer if anyone wants it:**

So I loaded all the images at the declaration block of my code:

```
SDL_Surface* items[5] = {
    IMG_Load("item1.png"),
    IMG_Load("item2.png"),
    IMG_Load("item3.png"),
    IMG_Load("item4.png"),
    IMG_Load("item5.png")
    };

    SDL_Surface* texts[5]{
         TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: House" , White),
         TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Road 1" , White),
         TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Road 2" , White),
         TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Junction" , White),
         TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, "Selected item: Park" , White)

    };
```

And then:

```
tableTexture[placex][placey] = items[hand - 1];
handitem = items[hand - 1];
text = texts[hand - 1];
```

So now I don't load everything every frame.

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/nevemlaci/citybuildersdl2

Comment: Make sure you do this inside of main or something that main calls, if you do this at global scope you could get some weird behaviors.

It may be better to store the file names at global scope (or wherever you like) then put the loaded images into an array like you did above, e.g

const char* item_image_paths[] = {"item1.png", /*...*/};

//..in main...//
SDL_Surface* items[5] = { IMG_Load(item_image_paths[0]), /*...*/ };
//...

Comment: I did it in my main function, don't worry. But thank you for your help anyways, I may do the filepath storing too as you said :)